# Navigation bar is compressed

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

My navigation bar is compressed, I can't even select the bar button item.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode? Does it look like that when you run it?

Comment: restarting doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check height constraints of navigation bar.